# Replacing a value called via PHP, with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a combination of `WordPress` and the `qTranslate` plugin to acheive a multi-language property site. I'm calling some hardcoded values in a custom way, as there's no default way in the theme to allow qTranslate in the labels.

**So currently I've got:**

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true) && $property_pool): ?>
            <li>
                <p><?php echo PROP_POOL_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true);?></p>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Only problem is, 'property_pool' value is also coming in 1 language. I need to be able to modify the outcome directly on this page. If it's Yes, replace it with `<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Si<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->`, and if it's No, replace it with `<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->`.

I've looked a few things up, like `str_replace` but I'm a total beginner and have no idea how I can incorporate this into an existing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've described it, this should work

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true) && $property_pool):
    $property_pool_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true);
    if ($property_pool_meta == 'Yes') {
        $property_pool_meta = '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Si<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->';
    }
    elseif ($property_pool_meta == 'No') {
        $property_pool_meta = '<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->';
    } ?>
    <li>
        <p><?php echo PROP_POOL_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php echo $property_pool_meta; ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My only concern would be that that wouldn't be processed by qTranslate.  To get qTranslate to process it, I'd replace

```
<?php echo $property_pool_meta; ?
```

with

```
<?php _e( $property_pool_meta ); ?>
```

qTranslate hooks into the [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) and [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) functions.

**Edit**

If you have lots of values, you might be better off doing something like this (I haven't tested it, so there might be a syntax error or two in there):

```
<?php 
$property_pool_map = array(
    'Yes' => '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Si<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->',
    'No' => '<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->'
);

if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true) && $property_pool):
    $property_pool_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true);
    if (isset($property_pool_map[$property_pool_meta])) {
        $property_pool_meta = $property_pool_map[$property_pool_meta];
    } ?>
    <li>
        <p><?php echo PROP_POOL_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php echo $property_pool_meta; ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hobo, that did it! I knew there'd be something I could copy and paste to various items and just rename the main value. And yeah, I had to use _e( $property_pool_meta ) .

Comment: If there were three items, Would I just add another `elseif ($custom_meta=='Value') { $custom_meta ='value2'; }`?

Comment: Yes; though if you have lots of potential values, it'd probably be best to put them in an array, and look them up that way.  See my edit.